# Are the real and imaginary parts of Riemann zeta equal to each other by multiplication of a Riemann Siegel theta function expression?

Tags: complex-numbers, riemann-zeta, polygamma

It appears that the real part of Riemann zeta is related to the imaginary part by this formula:

$$\Re\left(\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}+i t\right)\right)=\frac{\Im\left(\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}+i t\right)\right) (\cos (2 \vartheta (t))+1)}{-\sin (2 \vartheta (t))}$$

and vice versa:

$$\Im\left(\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}+i t\right)\right)=\frac{\Re\left(\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}+i t\right)\right) (-\sin (2 \vartheta (t)))}{\cos (2 \vartheta (t))+1}$$

where $\vartheta (t)$ is the [Riemann Siegel theta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Siegel_theta_function) function.

> How does one prove this formula above?

I guess a starting point should be these formulas for the real and imaginary parts of the Riemann zeta function:

$$\Re\left(\zeta \left(a+ib\right)\right)=\frac{1}{2} \left(\zeta \left(a+ib\right)+\zeta \left(a-ib\right)\right)$$

$$\Im\left(\zeta \left(a+ib\right)\right)=\frac{1}{2 i}\left(\zeta \left(a+ib\right)-\zeta \left(a-ib\right)\right)$$

What I would do is to look at the series expansion of:

$$-\frac{\sin (2 \vartheta (t))}{\cos (2 \vartheta (t))+1}$$

```
Clear[t];
Normal[Series[(-Sin[RiemannSiegelTheta[t]*2])/(1 +
Cos[RiemannSiegelTheta[t]*2]), {t, 0, 1}]]
N[%, 20]
```

This gives:
$$\frac{1}{2} t \left(\log (\pi )-\psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\right)$$
and numerically:
$$2.6860917096128327911 t$$
where $\psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)$ is the [Polygamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function) function.

Then I would compare it to the series expansion of:
$$\frac{\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}+i t\right)-\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}-i t\right)}{\frac{1}{2} (2 i) \left(\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}+i t\right)+\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}-i t\right)\right)}$$

which Mathematica:

```
Normal[Series[((Zeta[1/2 + I*t] - Zeta[1/2 - I*t])/(2*
       I))/((Zeta[1/2 + I*t] + Zeta[1/2 - I*t])/2), {t, 0, 1}]]
N[%, 20]
```

tells me is:
$$\frac{t \zeta '\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}$$
and numerically:
$$2.6860917096128327911 t$$

I then asked Mathematica to compare the two numerically equivalent expressions symbolically with the True Query command `TrueQ`:

```
TrueQ[1/2 t (Log[\[Pi]] - PolyGamma[0, 1/4]) == (
  t Derivative[1][Zeta][1/2])/Zeta[1/2]]
```

But the computer says no, Mathematica returns False although numerically the values so far are identical.

> So is the real question to show that:
>   $$\frac{1}{2} t \left(\log (\pi )-\psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\right)=\frac{t \zeta '\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}$$
>   ?

I know that: $$\log (\pi )=\frac{\zeta '(0)}{\zeta (0)}-\log (2)$$ but that won't take me far will it?

Update:

I misread the Mathematica manual at first and missed that this is an equality:

$$\frac{1}{2} t \left(\log (\pi )-\psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\right)=\frac{1}{2} t \left(\log (\pi )-\frac{\Gamma '\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}\right)$$

Therefore the task is to show that:
$$\frac{1}{2} t \left(\log (\pi )-\frac{\Gamma '\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}\right)=\frac{t \zeta '\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}$$

```
TrueQ[1/2 t (Log[\[Pi]] - Gamma'[1/4]/Gamma[1/4]) == (
  t Derivative[1][Zeta][1/2])/Zeta[1/2]]
```

returns False.

```
N[1/2 t (Log[\[Pi]] - Gamma'[1/4]/Gamma[1/4]) == (
  t Derivative[1][Zeta][1/2])/Zeta[1/2], 20]
```

returns:
(2.6860917096128327911 t == 2.6860917096128327911 t)
True

Comment: is there any reason as to why the Wikipedia definition for the Riemann-Siegel expresses $\frac{1}{2}$ in decimal notation for the first term of the numerator of the expression inside arg?

Comment: @AdamL Not any reason that I can think of. $$\theta(t) = \arg \left(\Gamma\left(\frac{0.5+it}{2}\right)\right) - \frac{\log \pi}{2} t$$ Probably just a single editors choice for that particular part, equally accurate though.

Comment: Sure I know it doesn't matter I don't know why I get a bee in my bonnet over silly things like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will you look at the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_function) of $Z(t)$ and $\vartheta(t)$ ?

---

$$\text{For } t \in \mathbb{R}, \ Z(t) \in \mathbb{R}, \qquad \zeta(\tfrac{1}2+it) = Z(t) e^{-i \vartheta(t)} $$
thus
$$\Re(\zeta(\tfrac{1}2+it)) = Z(t) \cos(\vartheta(t)), \qquad Z(t) = \frac{\Re(\zeta(\frac{1}2+it))}{\cos(\vartheta(t))}$$
$$\Im(\zeta(\tfrac{1}2+it)) = - Z(t) \sin(\vartheta(t)) = -\frac{\Re(\zeta(\frac{1}2+it))}{\cos(\vartheta(t))}\sin(\vartheta(t)) =\frac{ -\Re(\zeta(\frac{1}2+it))\sin(2\vartheta(t))}{1+\cos(2\vartheta(t))}$$
where I used $$\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)} =\frac{\cos(x)\sin(x)}{\cos(x)^2}=\frac{\sin(2x)}{1+\cos(2x)}$$